# Python bot, adding reactions

Tags: python, discord

I am making a python bot, that when someone types [react, the bot will react with () or in Unicode (U+1F611)

I currently have this code:

```
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('[react'):
  author=message.author
  discord.Client.add_reaction(author,'U+1F611')
```

when I try this and type [react, I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/runner/.site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in 
_run_event
yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
File "main.py", line 21, in on_message
discord.Client.add_reaction(author,'U+1F611')
TypeError: add_reaction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'emoji
```

If anyone knows what is wrong, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Have you tried '\U0001F611' ? Aren't you missing 'await'? https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/8j1ywl/discordpy_how_to_use_add_reaction/

Comment: Thanks, I think await was needed, but I am still getting errors, it goes like this:

Comment: if message.content.startswith('[react'):
        author=message.author
        await discord.Client.add_reaction(message.author,'\U0001F611')

Comment: and the error still is : Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 18, in on_message
    await discord.Client.add_reaction(message.author,'\U0001F611')
TypeError: add_reaction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'emoji'

Comment: sorry comments are weird, that might be hard to read

Comment: Also, I guess you should pass message and not message.author.

Comment: @sehigle message works, but the whole emoji thing won't work, I am trying '\U0001F611' too.

Comment: I got it! thanks to @sehigle original comment, the proper code was :                await client.add_reaction(message,"\U0001F44D") - (for thumbs up)                                 I had DISCORD in the start, when it is editing the clients message! Thanks alot the people here are always so helpful